# Java Hashmap getter for Jsf hiddenfield

Tags: java

I have a JSF page which contains a hiddenfield tag that stores values from a React application and these values get passed on to a backing bean where a Map object is set, which is set to this tag.

The problem I have is when a user first goes to this page, the getter will be empty, which is correct. But this isn't the problem, the actual problem is that the hiddenfield will be expecting a string not a Map object. This scenario is only when the page is loaded for the first time and the getter won't apply afterwards.

I have tried setting an empty map object using the toString() function but when going to the page for the first time, it throws an exception of out of bounds.

Is there a correct way where a I can have an empty map object but the object returns an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this?

```
hashMap.isEmpty() ? "" : hashMap.toString()
```

**UPDATE**

I removed "new" before `Collections.emptyMap()`

```
public String getBookDetails() {
    Map<String, String> emptybookdeails = Collections.emptyMap();
    /* fetching book details from React */
    return emptybookdeails.isEmpty() ? "" : emptybookdeails.toString();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I have not explained myself very well. In the getter I want to set the Hashmap to be empty and return a empty string.  Now I have tried this but it throws an exception as described earlier

Comment: Public String getBookDeails()

Comment: Public String getBookDeails() { Map<String,string> emptybookdeails = new Collections.emptyMap(),; emptybookdeails.toString();}

Comment: @Andy5 I have updated my answer. If you do not need this I totally misunderstood you.